# inverting an image with 'abs' and numpy

Tags: image, numpy, pooling

```
img = Image.open(path)
data_origin = np.asarray( img, dtype='uint8' )
data = np.array(data_origin) # 300 x 300 x 4

1)for i in range(data.shape[0]): # invert colors
    for j in range(data.shape[1]):
        for k in range(3): # only first three dims r g b
            data[i,j,k] = abs(data[i,j,k] - 255)

2)data[:,:,:3] = np.abs(data[:,:,:3] - 255) # why does it work worse?
''''
applying max pooling
...
end
```

When I transform the array into an image and look at it, the image, that have been inverted by first method, has better quality then inverted by second one. And I cannot understand why. Can you help me?

[first method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcukt.png)

[second method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxNdB.png)

Comment: Could you please post the original image. (I don't like to post answers without testing them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One bug to look out for performing both methods on the same `data` object. However, I've tried your methods on my own images, and the results were incorrect.

You can **fix the behavior** in method two by rephrasing the calculation to `255 - data[:,:,:3]`. This solution assumes that your images have a max values of (255, 255, 255) for (R,G,B).

```py
# old method
data[:,:,:3] = np.abs(data[:,:,:3] - 255) 

# new method
data[:,:,:3] = 255 - data[:,:,:3]
```

You can verify this method by running the code

```py
img = Image.open(path)
data = np.asarray(img, dtype='uint8' )
experiment_1 = np.copy(data)
experiment_2 = np.copy(data)

# Perform method 1 on experiment_1
# ...
# Perform method 2 on experiment_2
# ...

print(np.all(experiment_1 == experiment_2))
```

If you want to understand **why** the code is behaving this way, it's because your code `data_origin` array is datatype `np.uint8`. [`uint8` is an unsigned integer with 8 bits](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint8.html) meaning it can only be values from [0,255]. Subtracting a uint8 by 255 doesn't result in a negative number, but an overflow of x - 255.

For example,

```py
a = np.array([10, 100, 125, 250], dtype='uint8')
print(a - 255) # incorrect
>> array([ 11, 101, 126, 251], dtype=uint8)

print(255 - a) # correct
>> array([245, 155, 130,   5], dtype=uint8)
```

Even though `np.abs(data[:,:,:3] - 255)` should behave like `255 - data[:,:,:3]` (because `f(x) = abs(x-255)` equals `f(x) = 255 -x` for domain in range [0, 255]), the datatype makes this conversion incorrect.

Another fix to this code would be to replace `dtype='uint8'` to `dtype='int32'` (because int32 allows for negative values). However, I don't recommend this solution because int32 is much larger than uint8.